# Norm of "tensoring" with the identity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces

Consider a Banach space $E$ and a discrete set $X$. For an operator $T$ on $\ell^2(X)$ I can consider and induced operator $T'$ on the Bochner-Lebesgue space $\ell^2(X;E)$ of $E$-valued square-summable functions. This operator is defined by the same matrix representation, but simply acting on a larger Banach space. If we view $\ell^2(X;E)$ as a sort of tensor product of $\ell^2(X)$ and $E$ then $T'$ can be viewed as ``$T\otimes I$''.

My question is: are there Banach spaces $E$ other than the Hilbert space for which there is constant $C=C(E)$ and a norm estimate 
$$\Vert T'\Vert_{B(\ell^2(X;E))}\le C\,\Vert T\Vert_{B(\ell^2(X))}$$
for all $T\in B(\ell^2(X))$? Help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  This is Proposition 4.1 in Kwapien, "Isomorphic characterizations of inner product spaces by orthogonal series with vector valued coefficients."  Studia Math. 44 (1972), 583–595.  [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=341039)  See [Studia Math Archive](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-smv44i1p50bwm?q=bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-number-sm-1972-44-6;5&qt=CHILDREN-STATELESS)

To be precise, if $\mathcal F:L^2(\mathbb R) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb R)$ is the Fourier transform, then $\mathcal F: L^2(\mathbb R) \otimes E \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb R, E)$ is bounded if only if $E$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space.  As $L^2(\mathbb R)$ is isomorphic to $\ell^2$ via a choice of basis, this gives an example operator $T$ (all be it hard to write down as an operator on $\ell^2$).

There is more in the book by Defant and Floret on Tensor Norms.  Or see their survey paper "Continuity of Tensor Product Operators" (which, I'm afraid, I think is hard to get hold of).

Comment: Matt, the choice of a basis does not induce an isomorphism from $L^2(\mathbb R;E)$ to $\ell^2(E)$, i.e. is not a regular isomorphism between $L^2$ and $\ell^2$. However, your example is correct because $L^2$ embeds "regularly" in an ultraproduct of $\ell^2$.

Comment: @Mikael de la Salle  Right, yes!  That's a good observation.  (So, as an example on $L^2(\mathbb R)$ this is absolutely fine, but I was hasty to claim it was immediately an example on $\ell^2(X)$ for some $X$).